# jquery indexeddb plugin other statements execute before cursor iteration is complete

Tags: indexeddb

I am using **JQuery IndexedDB Plugin** available here http://nparashuram.com/jquery-indexeddb/ . Following is the code that I iterate over the objectstore **project_created**. When I run this code **ss** is alerted before objectstore **task_created** is iterated. But logically, **ss** should be alerted only after objectstore **task_created** is iterated.

```
$.indexedDB("sl_task_tracker").objectStore("project_created").each(function(elem){
        var count_tasks=0;
        $.indexedDB("sl_task_tracker").objectStore("task_created").each(function(item){
            if(item.value.project_id==elem.key)
                count_tasks++;
        });

        alert("ss");
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because IndexedDB uses an [aynchronous API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB#Asynchronous_API). Everything related to IndexedDB is done in "another thread" in order to *not block* the main thread (so that the web site won't appear to be fixed).

I don't know about this plugin, but you should check if you can pass a "onSuccess" function to your task, this way you can specify what's gonna happen once the task has been completed.

For more information about the plugin you're using, you can always ask the dev on his github page : https://github.com/axemclion/jquery-indexeddb

(Sorry about my bad technical english, feel free to edit in a much more understandable language)

Comment: I read the documentation and found that if I want to execute statements after cursor iteration is complete, I should do it in .done() function. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small jquery plugin (still very alpha) to ease the asynchrony and the otherwise confusing API:

https://github.com/ameyms/jquery-indexeddb

And I've tried to keep the API super simple:

```js
//Define and initialize an IndexedDB ...
var db = $.idb({
                    name:'foobar', 
                    version: 2,
                    drop: stores_to_be_deleted,
                    stores:list_of_stores
                });

// ... Add objects to a store
db.put(items, 'into_store').done(onsuccess);

//.. And delete objects from a store
db.remove('from_store', conditionFunc).done(onremoval);

//.. And not to forget fetching objects from a store
db.select('from_my_store', conditionFunc).done(function (items){

    console.log(items)
});
```

Hope you like it!